# Options for parsing/processing C++ files

Tags: c++, parsing, clang

So I have a need to be able to parse some relatively simple C++ files with annotations and generate additional source files from that.

As an example, I may have something like this:

```
//@ service
struct MyService
{
   int getVal() const;
};
```

I will need to find the //@ service annotation, and get a description of the structure that follows it.

I am looking at possibly leveraging LLVM/Clang since it seems to have library support for embedding compiler/parsing functionality in third-party applications. But I'm really pretty clueless as far as parsing source code goes, so I'm not sure what exactly I would need to look for, or where to start.

I understand that ASTs are at the core of language representations, and there is library support for generating an AST from source files in Clang. But comments would not really be part of an AST right? So what would be a good way of finding the representation of a structure that follows a specific comment annotation?

I'm not too worried about handling cases where the annotation would appear in an inappropriate place as it will only be used to parse C++ files that are specifically written for this application. But of course the more robust I can make it, the better.

Comment: Are you only going handle a subset where the only legal thing to follow your annotation is a `struct` with simple members? It'll get pretty complex very quickly since you're parsing C++.

Comment: Modifying a documentation generator would be easiest.

Comment: @Dervall initially, yes. Once I get to that point I may consider going further, but the initial requirements are for simple structs with simple members. I will never need to handle templates, virtual functions or overloaded operators.

Comment: Do you need to parse content of the struct/class, or just find out it's name? And are you set on the annotations, or would preprocessor-based annotations be an alternative?

Comment: @Jan Hudec I need to parse the interface of the struct, though I wouldn't need to parse any code within the struct's member functions. I am not really set on anything now. What do you mean by preprocessor-based annotations?

Comment: @Jan Hudec - do you mean something like a #pragma ? That is definitely a valid option that I hadn't yet thought about. Probably a better option, in fact.

Comment: No, I don't mean anything like a #pragma, because that's built in to the compiler. I mean a macro, that expands either to nothing or to some keyword in compile, but will be used to easily find the following identifier. So `#define service` and `service struct MyService` or `#define service struct` and `service MyService`. The Qt extensions work like this.

Comment: ... the advantage is actually more that if you make a typo, it won't be defined, so the compiler will tell you, while checking typos in the comments you have to do yourself.

Comment: Gotcha. That's another option. Looking at Clang it looks like the Preprocessor class has a hook specifically for handling pragmas, so I think it still may be a better option if I use Clang for parsing. If the source file is compiled with another compiler it would give a warning about an unknown pragma, but that's okay. If I used macros, I'd have to use something a little more obscure to avoid annoying conflicts.

Comment: Well a quick hack that I've found is that I can register an AST consumer with the Clang compiler, which fires a callback on type declarations. Then when a struct is declared I can get the line number and look for a comment on the preceding line(s). The comment would have to be on it's own line, but it's probably good enough for a quick proof of concept. I'm sure I can come up with something better after I spend some more time hacking at it :p

Answer (score 4):

One way I've been doing this is annotating identifiers of:

- classes
- base classes
- class members
- enumerations
- enumerators

E.g.:

```
class /* @ann-class */ MyClass 
    : /* @ann-base-class */ MyBaseClass
{
    int /* @ann-member */ member_;
};
```

Such annotation makes it easy to write a python or perl script that reads the header line by line and extracts the annotation and the associated identifier.

The annotation and the associated identifier make it possible to generate C++ reflection in the form of function templates that traverse objects passing base classes and members to a functor, e.g:

```
template<class Functor>
void reflect(MyClass& obj, Functor f) {
    f.on_object_start(obj);
    f.on_base_subobject(static_cast<MyBaseClass&>(obj));
    f.on_member(obj.member_);
    f.on_object_end(obj);
}
```

It is also handy to generate numeric ids (enumeration) for each base class and member and pass that to the functor, e.g:

```
    f.on_base_subobject(static_cast<MyBaseClass&>(obj), BaseClassIndex<MyClass>::MyBaseClass);
    f.on_member(obj.member_, MemberIndex<MyClass>::member_);
```

Such reflection code allows to write functors that serialize and de-serialize any object type to/from a number of different formats. Functors use function overloading and/or type deduction to treat different types appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing C++ code is an extremely complex task. Leveraging a C++ compiler might help but it could be beneficial to restrict yourself to a more domain-specific less-powerful format i.e., to generate the source and additional C++ files from a simpler representation something like `protobuf`s proto files or SOAP's WSDL or even simpler in your specific case.

Comment: Yes, I am actually using protobuf now. I'm just doing some research on alternatives to streamline workflows for projects that will only ever use C++ and don't need to worry about marshaling between languages.

Answer (score 1):

I did some very similar work recently.  The research I did indicated that there wasn't any out-of-the-box solutions available already, so I ended up hand-rolling one.

The other answers are dead-on regarding parsing C++ code.  I needed something that could get ~90% of C++ code parsed correctly; I ended up using [srcML](http://www.sdml.info/projects/srcml/).  This tool takes C++ or Java source code and converts it to an XML document, which makes it easier for you to parse.  It keeps the comments in-tact.  Furthermore, if you need to do a source code transformation, it comes with an reverse tool which will take the XML document and produce source code.

It works in 90% of the cases correctly, but it trips on complicated template metaprogramming and the darkest corners of C++ parsing.  Fortunately, my input source code is fairly consistent in design (not a lot of C++ trickery), so it works for us.

Other items to look at include [gcc-xml](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) and [reflex](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/reflex) (which actually uses gcc-xml).  I'm not sure if GCC-XML preserves comments or not, but it does preserve GCC attributes and pragmas.

One last item to look at is this [blog](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/05/03/parsing-cxx-with-gcc-plugin-part-1/) on writing GCC plugins, written by the author of the CodeSynthesis ODB tool.

Good luck!